# loop through DataTable while Changing the values in parameters Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, ajax, vb.net, c#-4.0

in my application I want to create webservice which generate the JSON DATA but my problem is that is it Generating the JSON Data First time but when I change the value of stored Procedure in Parameters then it don't loop through from DataRow.

here is my code

```
<WebMethod(EnableSession:=True)> _
    Public Shared Function Select_Search(ByVal MAKE As String, ByVal COLOR As String, ByVal CATAGORY As String, ByVal MODEL As String, ByVal TRANSMISSION As String, ByVal FUAL_TYPE As String, ByVal DRIVE As String, ByVal CHASSIS_NO As String) As SearchParameters()
        Dim ListbyClass As New List(Of SearchParameters)()
        Dim datatable As New DataTable()
        Dim myStock As New dsStockTableAdapters.newSTOCK_LISTTableAdapter()

        datatable = myStock.GetData(MAKE, "0", "0", "0", "0", DisplayType, "", "", "", "Any", "", "", "", "", "", 0, "", "", 0, "")

        Try
            'here when i change the above parameters value then looping is not working
            For Each rdr As DataRow In datatable.Rows

                Dim SRCH As New SearchParameters()
                SRCH.CHASSIS_NO = rdr("CHASSIS_NO").ToString()
                SRCH.MODEL = rdr("MODEL").ToString()
                SRCH.color = rdr("color").ToString()
                SRCH.TRANSMISSION = rdr("TRANSMISSION").ToString()
                SRCH.DOOR = rdr("DOOR").ToString()
                SRCH.MAKE = rdr("MAKE").ToString()
                SRCH.Image1 = rdr("Image1").ToString()
                SRCH.MODEL_DESCRIPTION = rdr("MODEL_DESCRIPTION").ToString()
                ListbyClass.Add(SRCH)

            Next
        Catch
        End Try

        Return ListbyClass.ToArray()

    End Function
```

Now for example when i pass 0 to MAKE parameter then is is generating the JSON because foreach loop will work in datatable.Rows but as i change the MAKE value to somthing like 23 it will not loop through the DataTalbe Rows and JSON will not be Generated

Here is my Ajax method script i am passing values to parameters by using jQuery.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        function StockList() {
            $("#update").empty();
            var make = $('#<%= ddlMake.ClientID %>').val();
            var color = $('#<%= ddlColor.ClientID %>').val();
            var catagory = $('#<%= ddlCat.ClientID %>').val();
            var model = $('#<%= ddlMakeModel.ClientID %>').val();
            var transmission = $('#<%= ddltransmission.ClientID%>').val();
            var fual_type = $('#<%= rdfuelType.ClientID%>').val();
            var drive = $('#<%= ddldrive.ClientID %>').val();    
            var chassis_no = $('#<%= txtChassis_No.ClientID %>').val();

            var data = { MAKE: make, COLOR: color, CATAGORY: catagory, MODEL: model, TRANSMISSION: transmission, FUAL_TYPE: fual_type, DRIVE: drive, CHASSIS_NO: chassis_no }
            var jsonData = JSON.stringify(data);

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "stocklist.aspx/Select_Search",
                data: jsonData,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data);

                    var j = 1;
                    var count = 9;

                    for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {
                        var output = '<ul class="selection page-' + (i == count || (i && !(i % 9)) ? j++ : j) + '">';
                        output += '<li >';
                        output += '<table><tr>';
                        output += '<td><img src="http://localhost:37245/NewPeaceAuto - Steer_Well/WebStock_Images/' + data.d[i].Image1 + '" alt=""/></td>';
                        output += '<td>CHASSIS NO:</td><td>' + data.d[i].CHASSIS_NO + '</td>';
                        output += '<td>MODEL:</td><td>' + data.d[i].MODEL + '</td>';
                        output += '<td>COLOR:</td><td>' + data.d[i].color + '</td>';
                        output += '<td>TRANS:</td><td>' + data.d[i].TRANSMISSION + '</td>';
                        output += '<td>DOOR:</td><td>' + data.d[i].DOOR + '</td>';
                        output += '<td>MAKE:</td><td>' + data.d[i].MAKE + '</td>';
                        output += '</tr></table></li></ul>';
                        $("#update").append(output);
                        count = count + 9;
                    }

                }
            });
        }
</script>
```

How to loop throwgh the DataTable no matter which values will be passed in parameters  like below

```
                             22     5        3       11       2
datatable = myStock.GetData(MAKE, MODEL, CATAGORY, COLOR, FUAL_TYPE .....)
```

Comment: First question:  are you sure that the parameters you pass in result in data being returned?  If no data is being returned, you're not going to get any looping behavior.

Comment: yes i am sure it is returing a data but when i change the values in parameters(that values are also in Database) then it will not loop through the DataRow

Comment: I should have asked:  is it the WebMethod looping that isn't working, or the looping in your Success function in javascript?

Comment: it`s a webmethod looping which is not working while changing the values in parameters but it`s looping when i paas 0 instead of MAKE value either this value "0" will be from dropdownist selected value or manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I notice that you have an empty `Catch` statement.  If you know for a fact that this line:

```
datatable = myStock.GetData(MAKE, "0", "0", "0", "0", DisplayType, "", "", "", "Any", "", "", "", "", "", 0, "", "", 0, "")
```

... returns data when `MAKE` is "23" - that `datatable` will contain records - then what I suspect may be happening is that something in the `Try` block is causing an error.  Since you have an empty `Catch` statement, you don't know what that error is, and the code continues on.

Try either removing the `Try .. Catch .. End Try` code from around the code, or put something in the `Catch` block to tell you when you have an error.

ETA:  If no errors are showing up, then the most likely possibility is that your table `datatable` has 0 rows.  A quick way to find out:  add the following line before your `For Each`:

```
 System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(datatable.Rows.Count > 0);
```

Run your code (in debug mode, or nothing will happen) and see if you get a message box indicating that the assertion is NOT true.

Comment: i have checked it also it`s not giving an exception in Catch block either.. i dont know why this is not looping through the DataRow when parameters value will be changed

Comment: infect i have removed the try catch block now

Comment: I have added another suggestion to my answer.